# How to paste images along a circular path in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, python-imaging-library

### Introduction

I am trying to recreate the Twitter Interaction Circles in Python. But, I am stuck at the creation of the image.

So far, I have been able to circle-crop the square avatars and place them in the center of a blank image created using Pillow.

How to place these images in the circular fashion around the center image?

I would appreciate any kind of help. I'm kind of a beginner in image manipulation.

### Sample Image

[image]

### What I have been able to achieve using Pillow:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO.  A circular pattern implies placing images in a circle.  Find the optimal radius and spread each image along the perimeter of the circle.  If you need multiple levels, repeat it with different radii.

Comment: it needs `math` to calcuate position on circle with radius `R` and in `angel` - like  `x = R * sin(angle) + center_x` , `y = R * cos(angle) + center_y` . Top has angle `0`, bottom has angle `180`, left/right has angle `90`/`270` (or `270`/`90`). You have to remeber that Python use `radians` in `math.sin()`, math.cos()` so you need `sin(math.radians(180))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It need rather basic math (mathematical formula for a circle) to calculate position.

If you have circle with radius `R` and you have to put in angle `angle`

```
  x = R * cos(angle) + center_x
  y = R * sin(angle) + center_y
```

`Top` has angle `0`, `bottom` has angle `180`, `left`/`right` has angle `90`/`270` (or `270`/`90`).

You have to remeber that Python use `radians` instead of `degrees` in `math.sin()`, `math.cos()` so you need `math.sin(math.radians(180))` to calculate for `180 degrees`.

If you want to put `8` images on circle then you need angle `360 / 8` which gives `45` so first image can be on angle `45 * 1`, second on `45 * 2`, etc.

if you want with offset `5` degrees then `(45 * 1) + 5`, second on `(45 * 2) + 5`, etc.

---

I'm not sure as for size of images. Circle has circuit

```
 circuit = 2 * PI * R
```

so for `8` images every image should use circle with `diagonal` smaller then

```
 diagonal = circuit / 8
```

which gives radius

```
 radius = diagonal / 2
```

To create this circle you will need image with

```
 width  = diagonal
 height = diagonal
```

---

If you have 8 images on circut then you have 7 gaps between images.

If you want gaps with size 5 pixels then you may need

```
 gap = 5

 diagonal = (circuit - 7*gap) / 8
```

Comment: I was thinking to create some code with pillow but I had no time (and images)

Comment: Anyways...thanks a lot!! I figured it out! It's worklng!!